# 混合分布をプロットする方法

Tags: python, python3, matplotlib

平均パラメータを`m=0`とし、分散`s1=5`が80%、分散`s2=1`が20%の混合分布をプロットしたいです。イメージとしては標準正規分布よりも裾がやや重い分布がプロットされるはずです。
色々調べてみたのですが、例やライブラリなどを見つけることができなかったので質問させていただきました。
どなたかやり方がわかる方いらっしゃいましたら回答よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

特に説明はしませんが、以下の様になります。

```py
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate two normal distributions
n_sample = 1000000
data = np.stack((
  np.random.normal(size=n_sample, loc=0, scale=math.sqrt(5)),
  np.random.normal(size=n_sample, loc=0, scale=1)
), axis=-1)

# random choice by probabilities
idx = np.random.choice(np.arange(2), size=(n_sample,), p=(0.8, 0.2))
sample = data[np.arange(n_sample), idx]

# plot
plt.hist(sample, bins=250, density=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]